# where to store a log file name in python?

Tags: python, module, python-3.x

I have a Python program that consists of several modules. The "main" module creates a file variable `log_file` for logging the output; all the other modules would need to write to that file as well.

However, I don't want to import the "main" module into other modules, since it would be a really weird dependency (not to mention it might not even work due to circular dependency).

Where, then, should I store the `log_file` variable?

EDIT:

Following @pyfunc answer - would this be ok:

```
--- config.py ---
# does not mention log_file
# unless it's required for syntax reasons; in which case log_file = None
# ...

--- main.py ---
from datetime import datetime
import config.py
log_filename = str(datetime.now()) + '.txt'
config.log_file = open(log_filename, 'w')
# ...

--- another_module.py ---
import config.py
# ...
config.log_file.write(some_stuff)
```

Comment: there doesn't seem to anything py3k-specific in this question.

Comment: I'd recommend using logging package with config files instead of custom solution.

Comment: I'm just printing out the output, not errors. I guess I could still use the logging package... Though I felt it's an overkill, where I just need to print things to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to take all that code into another module so that you could import it in main file and other modules as well.

Hope you have checked on : http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html

Answer (score 2):

Put the "global" variable in a "settings" module.

settings.py

```
log_file = "/path/to/file"
```

main.py

```
import settings
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename=settings.log_file,level=logging.DEBUG)

logging.debug("This should go to the log file")
```

other_module.py

```
import logging
logging.debug("This is a message from another place.")
```

While the [logging module](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) may solve your immediate problem and many others, the settings module pattern is useful for a lot of other things besides log file names. It is used by Django to configure just about everything.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking of doing (in config.py in my edited code above), but I need to assign the filename in main.py I think because it depends on the time when the script is called. Config.py would be imported many times, and so I don't want to keep changing the file name.

Comment: In your example, log_file doesn't have to be a global variable, since logging module will take over. But I understand the idea.